# Why is $0.1 =1$ in the $p$-adic numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, field-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I have been looking at $p$-adic numbers recently. Unless I am mistaken, if 
$$
\alpha = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ip^i
$$
then we write
$$
\alpha = 0.a_0a_1a_2a_3\dots
$$
With this we would get that $1 = 0.1$. That is, the multiplicative identity in the field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is $0.1$.

What I don't understand is why we don't say that
$$
\alpha = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ip^i
$$
is equal to $a_0.a_1a_2a_3\dots$

instead so that $1=1$.

EDIT: I would like an answer so that I can accept. If you would include in that answer a discussion of why the convention above is good for $p$-adic numbers, that would be appreciated.

Comment: We want the "decimal" point to separate the fractional and integral parts, just like with reals. The difference is that they switched sides. With the $p$-adics the fractional part is to the left of the separator.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Oh..... that explains a lot actually. So, just be sure I understand, this is then also the reason that when multiplying we go right to left instead of left to right?

Comment: Not sure I follow. I would start a multiplication of two $p$-adics from the left, i.e. the negative powers of $p$. This is because to determine the coefficient at position $p^k$ I need to process all the earlier powers $p^\ell, \ell<k$, in case there is some carry. In this sense the $p$-adics behave a lot like the Laurent series of meromorphic functions (poles of finite order only), where we process the principal parts first because highest pole order term will be easiest to calculate.

Comment: I would rather write $\dots a_3a_2a_1a_0$, it's potentially infinite to the left. Note that $\dots999=-1$ among $10$-adic numbers.

Comment: I’m in strong and total agreement with @Berci. Once you write numbers like that, the algorithms for addition, subtraction, and multiplication are *exactly* what you learned in elementary school, always proceeding from right to left. Division is trickier, but is easily managed.

Comment: @Berci: The problem with your notation is that the $p$-adic metric would make the sequence $1., 10., 100., 1000., \ldots$ approach $0$ in your notation. Isn't it more habitual to call this sequence $.1, .01, .001, .0001, \ldots$?

Comment: @darijgrinberg Right, because the $p$-adic absolute value of $100\cdots0$ (with $n$ zeroes) is $p^{-n}$. I have never met anyone who puts the decimal point of the $p$-adics to the left like that. If you do, then it means that when mapping an integer written in base $p$ into the $p$-adics, you have to reflect the digits. Do you really want to say that $(11010)_2$, an integer in base $2$, is the $2$-adic number $.01011$?

Answer (score 1):

I think the most compelling reasons are that

1. It is common to solve algebraic equations over the integers by proving *a priori* bounds on their size, finding all solutions over $\mathbb{F}_p$ for some "good" prime $p$, Hensel lifting the solutions digit by digit until we reach the bounds and either find or rule out an integer solution. Prominent examples include

   - factorization of polynomials over the integers using the [Zassenhaus–Berlekamp method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials#Modern_methods) and
   - producing points on hyperelliptic cuves using  the [Chabauty–Coleman method](https://math.bu.edu/people/jbala/nato_lectures.pdf).
2. We frequently use continuity of $p$-adic functions to summarize infinite families of congruence relations among integers. For example,

   - $p$-adic continuity of the binomial coefficients encompasses Kummer's theorem, Lucas's theorem, and Fermat's little theroem,
   - $p$-adic continuity of the $p$-adic gamma function entails Wilson's theorem, and
   - $p$-adic continuity of the $p$-adic zeta function is equivalent to Kummer's congruences.